# Sketch of a concave function from log-concave and log-linear functions.

Tags: statistics

Let $f:[0,1] \to [0, \infty)$ be a log-concave function and $g:[0,1] \to [0, \infty) $ a log-linear function. Both functions must satisfy those two conditions below:

1) $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx=\int_0^1 g(x)\,dx=1$ and

2) $\int_0^1 xf(x)\,dx=\int_0^1 xg(x)\,dx= \mu$.

Let $g(x)=\dfrac{e^{\theta x}\theta}{e^\theta -1}$, which fulfills 1) condition and for 2) $$\int_0^1 xg(x)\,dx=\frac{\theta}{e^\theta-1} \int_0^1 x e^{\theta x} \, dx= \frac{e^\theta(\theta-1)+1}{\theta(e^\theta-1)} =\mu(\theta)$$

Let define $h(x)=\log f(x) - \log g(x)$, where $\log g(x)=\theta x + \log \theta - \log(e^\theta - 1)$.

Since $h$ is concave and

- $\int_0^1 g(x)(e^{h(x)}-1)\,dx=0$
- $\int_0^1 xg(x)(e^{h(x)}-1)\,dx=0$

***this implies*** $\exists x_1, x_2$ and be $0 < x_1 < x_2 < 1$ such that:

- $h(x) \geq 0$ on $[x_1, x_2]$
- $h(x) \leq 0$ on $[0,1]$ \ $[x_1,x_2]$

I need any help from anyone on these two things:

1) Why is that "implication" that I highlighted?

2) How to sketch $h(x)$ to fulfill above conditions? Suppose that $f(x)$ is normal distribution density.

Thank you very much in advance for any help or hint!!

Comment: @Chill2Macht it was typo! yes u r right.

Comment: Also I'm a little unclear on what you mean by "how to sketch $h(x)$ to fulfill the above conditions"? Do you want to draw a rough picture? It's just a continuous function which is above the x-axis on $[x_1, x_2]$ and below the x-axis elsewhere. Or do you want the computation for the specific case that $f(x)$ is a normal distribution density?

Comment: @Chill2Macht, yes I wanted but I tried with Laplace density: $50exp(-|x-0.5|/0.01)$ where $50 \int_{0}^{1} xexp(-|x-0.5|/0.01)=0.5$ and $50 \int_{0}^{1} exp(-|x-0.5|/0.01)=1$, now I just need to find for what $\theta$ is $\mu(\theta)=0.5$ and I think it works!

Comment: For $\theta=\sqrt{2}$ I got $\mu(\sqrt{2})=0.5$ and the rest are calculations. I plotted in R and it looks good. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Well if my answer addressed the rest of your question, it may be helpful to future viewers of the question to mark the answer as accepted. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers If it did not address the rest of your question, please feel free to let me know why not so that the answer can be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $h$ is concave, $h$ is continuous. Because $h$ is continuous, the intermediate value theorem applies.

If, by means of contradiction, $h(x) > 0$ on all of $[0,1]$, then $e^{h(x)} > 1$ for all $x \in [0,1]$, and thus $e^{h(x)}g(x) > (1)g(x)= g(x)$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ (as well as $x g(x) e^{h(x)} > x g(x)$ for all $x \in [0,1]$). Then by monotonicity properties of integrals this would mean that $\int_0^1 e^{h(x)}g(x) dx > \int_0^1 g(x) dx$.